# C# how to find one item in listview and change his subitem

Tags: c#

Hello im trying to change one subitem from the checked ones in my list view like this example:

```
Name|Age|Gender|Country
Jack|12 |Male  |USA
Sam |14 |Male  |UK
Smit|16 |Male  |UK
Anna|15 |Female|USA
```

immagine that i have Sam and Anna checked, and im sending the names to another form, and i want to change the Age of Anna from the other form, but Sam is 1st and i only can change Sam i need one way to verify the name 1st and after verify change the value.

```
SaveTime = textBox1.Text;
ListViewItem itemcheck = Informacao.mListView.CheckedItems[0];
itemcheck.SubItems[1].Text = SaveTime;
```

Comment: Is it wpf/winform/asp application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to check the name before updating, you can just loop through your checked items. I have expanded this example to use a separate dialog.

### Form1.cs

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {


     string[] jack = { "Jack", "12", "Male", "USA" };
     string[] sam = { "Sam", "14", "Male", "UK" };
     string[] smit = { "Smit", "16", "Male", "UK" };
     string[] anna = { "Anna", "15", "Female", "USA" };

     mListView.Columns[0].Name = "Name";
     mListView.Columns[1].Name = "Age";
     mListView.Columns[2].Name = "Gender";
     mListView.Columns[3].Name = "Country";

     mListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(jack));
     mListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(sam));
     mListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(smit));
     mListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(anna));
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Form2 dialog = new Form2();
     dialog.PersonName = "Anna";

     if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        string newValue = dialog.NewValue;
        string name = dialog.PersonName;

        foreach (ListViewItem itemcheck in mListView.CheckedItems)
        {
           if (itemcheck.Text == name)
           {
              DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Confirm changes to {0} with {1}", name, newValue),
                                                    "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
              if (result == DialogResult.OK)
              {
                 //itemcheck.SubItems[chAge.Index].Text = txtValue.Text;
                 itemcheck.SubItems[mListView.Columns["Age"].Index].Text = newValue;
              }
              break;
           }
        }
     }
     dialog.Close();
     dialog.Dispose();
  }
```

Form2.cs

```
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public string PersonName
      {
         get { return txtName.Text; }
         set { txtName.Text = value; }
      }
      public string NewValue
      {
         get { return txtValue.Text; }
         set { txtValue.Text = value; }
      }
   }
```

On Form2, I have the 2 textboxes, as well as 2 buttons. The "Accept" button has its `DialogResult` property set to `OK`. The "Cancel" button has its `DialogResult` property set to `Cancel`.

Comment: Note: This is assuming WinForms.

Comment: I have done that and this is not getting inside of the foreach i think because i got no dialog and my timer don't stop

Comment: Edited to use a dialog form.

Comment: Thank you, i got it, you helped me with the 1st sample my problem was the break; it was exiting the foreach, i removed it and now it's working fine

Comment: The `break` shouldn't cause that problem. It's there to prevent it from continuing through the `foreach` after a match was found. Your timer should be stopped before that is reached as it's inside of the `if` above the break. But, I'm glad you were able to work out a solution with what I provided. Upvoting/accepting would be appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have done that and this is not getting inside of the foreach i think because i got no dialog and my timer don't stop

```
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Informacao.RadButtonValue == "Normal")
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem itemcheck in Informacao.mListView.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        if (itemcheck.Text == lblTimerScreenName.Text)
                        {
                            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Confirm changes to {0}", lblTimerScreenName.Text),
                                                                  "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                timer2.Stop();
                                itemcheck.SubItems[1].Text = lblTimerScreenName.Text;
                                SaveTime = textBox1.Text;
                                itemcheck.SubItems[9].Text = SaveTime;
                                itemcheck.SubItems[10].Text = Informacao.RadButtonValue;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
...
```

Comment: If you're not getting into the foreach, then your `RadButtonValue` check may be failing. Have you tested it to see?

Comment: Also, I see you have subitems going all the way to 10. You definitely should consider using keys.

Comment: My subitem number 10 is the last one, and my RadButtonValue is working fine

Comment: How can i assign one key? can you give me one example?

Comment: If Form2 is where your edits are made, you should make a dialog out of it. You can add public properties that hold the values. Show it from Form1 and then have it return a DialogResult. If the user chose OK, then apply the changes using the `foreach` to find it.

Comment: To use a key, you have to assign a value to the `Name` of each Column (not the same as the control name). Example: `mListView.Columns[1].Name = "Age";`. Then, it can be referred to like this: `itemcheck.SubItems[mListView.Columns["Age"].Index].Text = txtValue.Text;`. The reason you'd want to do this is if you ever make changes, such as inserting columns in the middle, your index positions would be off. By using keys, you can just change the top assignment to have the new values. If you dynamically create all of the columns, it's even easier.